# How I can give access to my custom plugin for editor roles user?

Tags: plugin-development, user-roles

Hi I have created a custom plugin. The plugin is working fine in the wp-admin. But now I want to my custom plugin can access the editor users role.

How I can manage the permission for my custom plugin.

Please help me out this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the code which you want to limit using the current_user_can() function.

```
if( current_user_can('editor') ) {
    // true if user is an editor
}
```

Depending on what you are trying to limit, you can put this conditional around the hook or action that you are adding, or use it to wrap specific functionality within the plugin.